# Why doesn't my While-Loop stop when comparing time_t values?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm new to C++ and not very deep into programming at all. Currently I'm playing with my RaspberryPi's GPIO using code from different sources, trying to adapt the code to my needs and understand what it's doing. So, for short, I'm trying to learn how programming in C++ works, by doing stuff and analyzing the outcome.

Now i've got stuck with a simple While-Loop:
I tried to use time_t to let the loop run for some seconds and stop afterwards. But the loop doesn't stop.

I know, there are lots of other ways to do the same thing, but instead of using other methods, I'm more intrested in understanding what's wrong with mine, so I can avoid running into similar problems in the future and keep my head from exploding.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Well, as I said, the loop doesn't stop and keeps running forever.

I thought, adding +20 to the time() result could somehow change the data type of my timeend-variable, so I'm adding +1 to the time() result of my timenow-variable as well. By this, I thought I could make sure the data types are the same. ...meanwhile I'm pretty sure it doesn't make a difference.

I've also added some printf, so I can see the actual values for each cycle. ...looks fine.

I thought, maybe those time_t values are not comparable in their current state. So I've added some "if" to check if those values can be compared or not. ...yes, they can and it's working very fine.

I've also tried to replace my timeend and timenow values with normal integer values like:

```
int i = 20
int iend = 0
while(i > iend)
    <all the other stuff>
    iend = iend + 1
```

...Well, like this it works fine.
Therefore I'm pretty sure, the problem is with those time_t values. But I don't see, why it works fine in "if", but not working at all in "while".

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
time_t timeend = (time(NULL) + 20); //creating a finish-value of 20sec in the future
time_t timenow = (time(NULL) + 1); //current time +1, "+1" only for bug fix

while(timeend > timenow){
    time_t timenow = (time(NULL) + 1);

    printf("%d\n", timeend); //printing values for bug fix
    printf("%d\n", timenow);

    if(timeend > timenow){   //checking if comparing those values timeend and timenow even works ...yes, it works.
        printf("bigger\n");
    }
    else if(timeend < timenow){
        printf("smaller\n");
    }
    else
        printf("error\n");

    delay (1000); //adding a little delay, so the loop only gets processed once per second.
    }
return 0;
}
```

And here's an extract from my console (only some part of where the loop should end):

```
...
1549566971 //value of timeend
1549566966 //value of timenow
bigger     //outcome of my "if" checkings, comparing those values
1549566971
1549566967
bigger
1549566971
1549566968
bigger
1549566971
1549566969
bigger
1549566971
1549566970
bigger
1549566971
1549566971
error      //here the while loop should stop, as timeend isn't bigger than timenow anymore, but it continues anyway.
1549566971
1549566972
smaller
1549566971
1549566973
smaller
1549566971
1549566974
smaller
1549566971
1549566975
smaller
1549566971
1549566976
smaller
1549566971
1549566977
smaller
...
```

Edit:

I've changed:

```
while(timeend > timenow){
    time_t timenow = (time(NULL) + 1);
```

into:

```
while(timeend > timenow){
    timenow = (time(NULL) + 1);
```

...now it works.

Comment: You have two variables called ”timenow”. A good book is much more efficient than poking and guessing.

Comment: ok, i'm facepalming myself right now. Thank you so much.

Comment: You have two variables called ”timenow”.  A compiler option can report the shadowed variable.  (Probably   -Wshadow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-declaration of

```
time_t timenow = (time(NULL) + 1);
```

your loop is testing the one outside(declared first) :)